# What is the geometric significance of the total differential being zero?

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-fields

If $U$ is a function of $x,y,z$ then the total increment of $U$ due to a transition of a point from $(x,y,z)$ to $(x+\delta x,y+\delta y,z+\delta z)$ is given by the total differential given by

$$dU = \frac {\partial U}{\partial x} dx + \frac {\partial U}{\partial y} dy +\frac {\partial U}{\partial z} dz$$

which implies

$$dU = ( \frac {\partial U}{\partial x} \hat i + \frac {\partial U}{\partial y} \hat j +\frac {\partial U}{\partial z} \hat k) \cdot (dx \hat i+dy \hat j+dz \hat k)$$

$$dU = \nabla U \cdot dl$$

where $$\nabla U = \frac {\partial U}{\partial x} \hat i + \frac {\partial U}{\partial y} \hat j +\frac {\partial U}{\partial z} \hat k$$ and  $$dl= (dx \hat i+dy \hat j+dz \hat k)$$

but if the total differential is zero what does it say about the gradient other than the fact that this implies that there is no change in U.

Edit:

$dU=0$ does not necesaarily mean change in U is zero but is or order higher than 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does NOT imply that there is no change in $U$.

What it implies is that the change in $U$ is of order 2 or higher; or to put it another way, the best "polynomial" approximation is a polynomial of degree 2 or higher. Think for example of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ at $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$.

Comment: But what does this signify about the gradient?

Comment: You asked "but if the total differential is zero what does it say about the gradient...?" Are you referring to the total differential at a specific point or at a larger collection of points?

Comment: Note $df=\vec{\nabla}f\cdot d\vec{r}=0$ means $\vec{\nabla}f$ and $d\vec{r}$ are orthogonal. This happens when $\vec{\nabla}f=\vec{0}$ or your displacement vector is perpendicular to the gradient of $f$ i.e. you're inching along some level set of $f$.

Comment: total differential at a specific point....but can total differential be define at more than one point at once?

Comment: Yes, the total differential of $U$ is defined, separately, for each point in $U$.

Comment: And regarding your first comment, the total differential being zero at a point is equivalent to the gradient vector at that point being the zero vector. This is true because the components of the total differential are identical to the components of the gradient vector: those components are the three partial derivatives $\partial U/\partial x$, $\partial U/\partial y$ and $\partial U/\partial z$ evaluated at that point..